# inserting onto a BST, "The method insert(myclass.TreeNode, int) is undefined for the type myclass"

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm a beginning Java student and have a homework assignment which requires me to build a simple BST using recursion. Should be simple, but it's giving me some trouble.

The Constructor Class and main() method are provided to me as follows

```
public static class TreeNode
{
   TreeNode LeftLink;
   int      Content;
   TreeNode RightLink;

}
// end class TreeNode

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
   TreeNode T = null;
   int      H, i;

   T = BuildSearchTree();

   H = Height(T);
   System.out.println("The number of nodes on the tree is " + NodeCount(T));
   System.out.println("The height of the tree is " + H);
   for (i = 0; i <= H; i++)
      System.out.println("The number of nodes on level " + i + " is " + CountLevel(T,i));
   // end for
}
```

My task is to fill to create a BinarySearchTree method without modifying anything already provided to me.

The BinarySearch Tree method requests a file filled with integers from the user, and recursively builds a BST from it.

My Compiler (Eclipse) is giving me an error under the title of my insert method "The method insert(myclass.TreeNode, int) is undefined for the type myclass"

I believe this has something to do with the way T=BuildSearchTree(); is declared in the main method, but frankly, I have no idea what's going on.

What I have so far is

```
public static TreeNode BuildSearchTree() throws IOException {

    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter the name of your word file (please include ''.data'' or ''.txt'' when inputting file name) (number of words in the word file must be less than 30.)");

    String datafile = Keyboard.next();

    Scanner InputFile = new Scanner(new File(datafile));

    int[] data = new int[1000];

    while(InputFile.hasNext()){
        int i;
        data[i]=InputFile.nextInt();
                i++;
        } //end while

    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
    TreeNode T = insert(T, data);} //end for




    private static TreeNode insert(TreeNode node, int content)
     {


        if (node == null)
        {
             node.Content=content;
        }

        else if (content <= node.Content)
             {
                 insert(node.LeftLink, content);
             }

        else
             {
                insert(node.RightLink, content);
             }                                      
         }
    return node;
}//end insert method

return T;

}//end BuildSearchTree
```

Comment: Why is `insert` declared inside `BuildSearchTree`?

Comment: according to My Professor, I can only edit the code inside BuildSearchTree. I could get this whole thing running easily on my own if I could place my insert method outside.

Comment: You have a missing close curly brace at the end of the BuildSearchTree method. I would *not* recommend putting close curly braces on the ends of lines with code because it messes up the auto-indenting. If you put that brace on its own line and then auto-indent, this will be easier to see.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not allow nested functions, so finish the code BuildSearchTree()   before starting the code for insert().

The call to insert in `T = insert(T, data);` should be something like `T = insert(T, data[i]);`

You need to declare `T` outside the loop if you want to use it after the loop.

You can't assume that the data file has less than 1000 elements, so you probably want to use a java.util.ArrayList rather than an array. You need to use the number of items actually read from the file in the loop around the call to insert rather than the literal value of 1000.

Your while loop should be something like:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>;
    while(InputFile.hasNext()){
        data.add(InputFile.nextInt());
    } //end while
    TreeNode T = new TreeNode();
    for(i=0; i<data.length(); i++){
        T = insert(T, data[i]);
    } //end for
    return T;
```